# como crear un array y manipularlo para enviarlo y contar sus elementos con JQuery

Tags: jquery

actualmente tengo la siguiente función que me extrae los `value` de unos select que clone:

```
var array_select = [];

function probar(e) {

  $('[name="mi_select[]"]').each(function (indice, elemento) {
    array_select = $(elemento).val();
    console.log(array_select);

  });
}
```

Cuando lo imprimo con `console.log()` me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
// 125
// 145
// 286
```

Esos `value` están bien, ahora yo quiero agarrar esos valores y meterlo dentro de un array para pasarlos a mi back, algo así:

```
fd.append('mi_variable', $('#array_select').val());
```

Cabe señalar que tengo pocos conocimientos en JQuery y no se como hacer el arreglo, además quiero contar cuantos elementos tiene para validar que no se incluyan mas de 4 select, por otro lado saber si tiene `values` repetidos ya que no se deben permitir valores repetidos, cualquier ayuda será bienvenida, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicado de la manera más sencilla, JQuery es una librería usada para el manejo de elementos en el DOM, no tiene mucho que ver con el manejo de arreglos.

Si vas a manejar arrays. necesitas usar JavaScript Vanilla.

Lo que estás haciendo ahí es reescribir la variable **array_select** de un tipo a otro.

```
array_select = [];
console.log(typeof array_select); // resultado -> object

array_select = 5;
console.log(typeof array_select); // resultado -> number

array_select = "Hola";
console.log(typeof array_select); // resultado -> string
```

Basicamente estás cambiando el tipo de variable.

Si lo que quieres es agregar datos a un arreglo, se utiliza **push**

Ejemplo

```
array = [];
console.log(aray); // resultado -> []

array.push("Hola");
console.log(aray); // resultado -> ["Hola"]

array.push("soy otro texto");
console.log(aray); // resultado -> ["Hola", "soy otro texto"]
```

Y para hacer el recorrido de un arreglo, puedes obtar por usar **forEach**

```
array = [25, 5, 9, 10];

array.forEach(item => {
   console.log(item) // imprimirá cada uno de los elementos por separado
})
```

Dentro de la función flecha puedes hacer tus validaciones

Comment: Gracias por toda la ayuda y el tiempo tomado en explicarme sobre la librería, pero no logro comprender como formar el array

Comment: Usas **array_select.push($(elemento).val());**. Por favor, te suguiero buscar más información sobre los arreglos en JavaScript